# Spring Security Custom Session management and Remember me not working

Tags: spring-security, remember-me, session-management

I have configured custom session management like :

```
<sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none">
<sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</sec:session-management>
```

And remember me like :

```
<sec:remember-me />
<sec:custom-filter ref="rememberMeFilter" after="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>

<bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">


<property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="theAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
<property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
<property name="key" value="springRocks"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="key" value="springRocks"/>
</bean>
```

and when i log-in with remember me check and close the browser and open the new browser again and remember me is not working, instead of that i am getting session exceeded error. Because i have set the max-sessions=1.

Can any one help me out from this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is working as expected. YOu are closing your browser, so the old session remains. You are opening the browser again, due to remember-me you are automatically logged in but this is prevented because the old session is still there.

Comment: @M.Deinum, you are right. But i want to implement it like "Gmail", you log-in to your gmail with "remember me" option and close your browser and open it again then it will automatically log-in to your account.

Comment: Combining remember-me with concurrent session isn't going to work. Unless you modify the remember-me to clean the sessions first but then that would basically render the concurrent session control useless.

Comment: @M.Deinum, So what will be the solution ? because i want to implement both. Do you have any other idea ? Thank You.

Comment: Why do you want concurrent-session control? Don't throw an exception in that case, which will invalidate the already existing session and start a new one. But not sure what you want. For some reason it feels like you want something that is mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue too, I wanted to use session concurrency control as well as remember-me. My config is slightly different, i dont throw an error to user if max-session is exceeded, instead i simply expire the old session so that the user can continue with the new session. With the spring provided beans it wont work as expected. As I login 2nd time, concurrency control kicks in and expires the old session, then the user continues with the newly created session. But when the user tries to access the system with the 1st session, ConcurrentSessionFilter detects that this session was expired and redirects to the configured *expired-url*, which is normal and expected.

But my requirement was different, if the user tries to use the 1st session, the 2nd session should be expired and the user should be re-authenticated and then a new session should be created for the user to continue. Basically, the user can switch between different browsers without actually entering username/password using the remember-me option checked-on, but there will be only one active session in the server. Session will be expired/created as and when user switches between different browsers.

I managed to achieve that by extending and customizing the spring beans. If your requirement is simmilar i could help u with my config.

Comment: Could you please help me with the configuration, I have the similar requirement in grails application. How did you achieve this?